# Wcf service operation contract change

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I recently added a parameter to one of the method of a wcf. It was a string parameter.

The thing is that I didn't update the service reference on the client side but I was still able to call the wcf service .....

Wasn't it suppose to break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client side had no idea that you updated the reference, so it won't throw a compile time error.

The service defaulted the string to null when it wasn't passed since it wasn't there which is perfectly valid.

Comment: is this behavior documented somewhere ?  I would of thought that it would throw some kind of exception ... when calling ?